# Increase performance of GROUP BY in postgres jsonb fields

Tags: postgresql, database-performance, query-performance, jsonb, postgresql-9.6

I'm trying to get jsonb performance to match that of a joined table that consists of the same data. So far so good, but I'm stuck on the following grouping query, which returns in about 1.6 seconds:

```
SELECT 
    x.metadata #>> '{fakeWeather, windDirection}' as wind_direction,
    COUNT(*) as count
FROM analytics.incidents x 
GROUP BY x.metadata #>> '{fakeWeather, windDirection}'
ORDER BY 1;
```

The tabular version returns in 0.8 seconds:

```
SELECT
    y.wind_direction,
    COUNT(*) as  count
FROM analytics.incidents x
INNER JOIN analytics.incidents_metadata_fakeweather y ON x."id" = y.incident_id
GROUP BY y.wind_direction
ORDER BY 1;
```

I've created the following index: `CREATE INDEX idx_metadata_btree_direction ON analytics.incidents ((metadata #>> '{fakeWeather, windDirection}'));`

Does anybody know how (or if) I can make the JSONB version faster?

Comment: I don't think indexing is actually going to help you, unless you've omitted a `WHERE` clause. You can look for yourself using `EXPLAIN` (which you should run and post the output of anyway). This might be a case of having to eat the downside of freeform JSON fields, though.

Comment: By eating the downside of freeform JSON, do you mean the bloat caused repeated property names?

Comment: I meant the slower performance. I wouldn't consider the bloat a downside unless and until it became provably a performance concern due to paging weirdness or what have you -- disk space is cheap.

Comment: If you have a properly normalized version why do you need json?

Comment: The shape of the data will change, so I'd rather not have a workflow that involves DDL.